# Is there any way to access parent object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a code like below, but can't seem to access the `data` object from `innerFn` function. Is there any way I can do this?

```
export default {
 data: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
 },
 fn: {
    innerFn: () => console.log(data.b)
 }
}
```

Comment: `this.data.b` .

Comment: @Tushar this doesn't work because calling `this` in innerFn would only lead to `fn` scope.

Comment: Any object can have multiple parents, so what you're looking for isn't possible *in general*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default {
 data: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
 },
 fn: {
    innerFn: () => console.log(default.data.b)
 }
```

}

This might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your js file

```
// name the file as follows 
var func = ()=>{
 console.log("triggered your function"); 
}


export default {
 data: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
 },
 fn: {
    val: 3,
    innerFn: func
 }
}
```

now you can call the function

```
fn.innerFn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your object a name and then you dont have to use `this` to access parent property.

```
const obj = {
 data: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
 },
 fn: {
    innerFn: () => console.log(obj.data.b)
 }
}

export default obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Self referencing is what the `this` keyword is for.

Using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) you can define the objects properties in a scope, wherein the `this` keyword will reference the parent object.

```js
var obj1 = Object.create(null, {
  data: {
    value: {
      a: "a",
      b: "b"
    }
  },
  fn: {
    value: function fn() {
      console.log(this.data.b);
    }
  }
});
//TEST
console.log(obj1.data.a);
obj1.fn();
//Alternative with functions
function obj2() {}
obj2.data = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b"
};
obj2.fn = function fn() {
  console.log(this.data.b);
};
console.log(obj2.data.a);
obj2.fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `this` keyword.

For Example:-

```
export default {
    data: {
        a: "World!"
    },
    methods: {
        consoleGreet: () => {
            console.log(`Hello, ${this.data.a}`)
        }
    }
}
```